# How to copy a file open from open dialog to other location in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

I have start a new application that converts video to image and then image to gif
every thing is ok if i put my video in side of the same folder but if i not put my video in the same folder of the project the ffmpeg its says no such file or directory. wen i click to chose my file with openfiledialog , how can i copy or move my chose video to the correct directory in this case C:\avitogifconverter\

I have try to move the file to other location but wen i try to move the file to a different location its say i can not find the directory but the directory exist. what i have miss here this is the code

This is my code

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
Dim fpsx = 10
Dim video = ""
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe")
Dim frame As Long 'individual frames
Dim tempdir As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\" ' images temp directory
Dim DestPath As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\"
Public Declare Auto Function FindWindowNullClassName Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindow" (ByVal lpClassname As Integer, ByVal lpWindownName As String) As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(tempdir)
    TextBox1.Text = "exp:-->video.avi or webm or flv"
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Text = fpsx


End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    fpsx = TextBox2.Text
    TextBox2.Text = fpsx

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start("cmd", "/k ffmpeg.exe -i " + TextBox1.Text + " -framerate 5/1 -filter:v fps=" + TextBox2.Text + " C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg")
    p.WaitForExit()

    If p.HasExited Then
        MsgBox("The Extraction Are Finish...")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        'TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        'TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim newdialog As New OpenFileDialog()
        If newdialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(newdialog.FileName, tempdir)
            MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(newdialog.FileName) & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(newdialog.FileName))
        End If
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text <> Nothing Then
        'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(TextBox1.Text, DestPath)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim args As String 'declare args
    args = " -i C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg -r 10 C:\avitogifconverter\out.gif "
    'args = " -i C:\avitogifconverter\out%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\avitogifconverter\out.mp4 "
    Dim proc As New Process
    Dim proci As New ProcessStartInfo
    proci.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ffmpeg.exe"
    proci.Arguments = args
    proci.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    proci.CreateNoWindow = True
    proci.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo = proci
    proc.Start()
    Do Until proc.HasExited = True
        Me.Text = "Saving"
    Loop
    Me.Text = "your video done"

    MsgBox("Done")
    Dim directoryName As String = "C:\avitogifconverter\"
    For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        File.Delete(deleteFile)
    Next

    'IO.Directory.Delete(tempdir, True)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Form2.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a debugging service - the reason so few of your posts get answers is because they amount to a code dump (complete with empty, unused event handlers) for someone else to debug for you.  VS comes with a fine debugger.  Fire it up and debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use 2 OpenFileDialog, but anyway you don't use the System.IO.File.Copy method correctly. Both of the parameters have to be **FILE** PATHS. Your mistake is that you use the second parameter as **DIRECTORY** PATH